# Error when reading HDF5 as a Dask Dataframe, why?

Tags: dataframe, dask, hdf5

**1. My problem**

I get the next error when trying to read my HDF5 file using Dask and I don't know why

```
>>> dd.read_hdf("test.h5", key="/RECORDS/STATES")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/hdf.py", line 514, in read_hdf
    for path in paths
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/hdf.py", line 514, in <listcomp>
    for path in paths
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/hdf.py", line 382, in _read_single_hdf
    for k, s, d in zip(keys, stops, divisions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/multi.py", line 1071, in concat
    raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

**2. The HDF5 file**

The file I'm tryig to read with Dask was generated by me using the C API of HDF5. If you ask, I generate the HDF5 using C, not Python (numpy, pandas), for the sake of performance because I need to parse many GB of unformatted data in ASCII. The data is stored in the file as a HDF5 Table (https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/Tables). The header of my files looks like this:

```
HDF5 "rhoPimpleExtrae10TimeSteps.00.1iter.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   ATTRIBUTE "hdf5_metadata_apps" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
      DATASPACE  SCALAR
   }
   ATTRIBUTE "hdf5_metadata_date" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
      DATASPACE  SCALAR
   }
   ATTRIBUTE "hdf5_metadata_hwcpu" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 48 ) / ( 48 ) }
   }
   ATTRIBUTE "hdf5_metadata_hwnodes" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( 1 ) }
   }
   ATTRIBUTE "hdf5_metadata_name" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
      DATASPACE  SCALAR
   }
   ATTRIBUTE "hdf5_metadata_nodes" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I64LE
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( 1 ) }
   }
   ATTRIBUTE "hdf5_metadata_path" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
      DATASPACE  SCALAR
   }
   ATTRIBUTE "hdf5_metadata_threads" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 48 ) / ( 48 ) }
   }
   ATTRIBUTE "hdf5_metadata_time" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I64LE
      DATASPACE  SCALAR
   }
   ATTRIBUTE "hdf5_metadata_type" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
         STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
         STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
         CSET H5T_CSET_UTF8;
         CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
      }
      DATASPACE  SCALAR
   }
   GROUP "RECORDS" {
      DATASET "COMMUNICATIONS" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
            H5T_STD_U32LE "CPU Send ID";
            H5T_STD_U32LE "Phy. Task Send ID";
            H5T_STD_U32LE "Log. Task Send ID";
            H5T_STD_U32LE "Thread Send ID";
            H5T_STD_U64LE "Log. Send Time";
            H5T_STD_U64LE "Phy. Send Time";
            H5T_STD_U32LE "CPU Receive ID";
            H5T_STD_U32LE "Phy. Task Receive ID";
            H5T_STD_U32LE "Log. Task Receive ID";
            H5T_STD_U32LE "Thread Receive ID";
            H5T_STD_U64LE "Log. Receive Time";
            H5T_STD_U64LE "Phy. Receive Time";
            H5T_STD_U64LE "Size";
            H5T_STD_U64LE "Tag";
         }
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 67574 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED ) }
         ATTRIBUTE "CLASS" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 6;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_0_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 12;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_10_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 18;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_11_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 18;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_12_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 5;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_13_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 4;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_1_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 18;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_2_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 18;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_3_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 15;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_4_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 15;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_5_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 15;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_6_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 15;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_7_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 21;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_8_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 21;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_9_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 18;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "TITLE" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 22;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "VERSION" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 4;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
      }
      DATASET "EVENTS" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
            H5T_STD_U32LE "CPU ID";
            H5T_STD_U16LE "APP ID";
            H5T_STD_U32LE "Task ID";
            H5T_STD_U32LE "Thread ID";
            H5T_STD_U64LE "Time";
            H5T_STD_U64LE "Event Type";
            H5T_STD_U64LE "Event Value";
         }
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 3643006 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED ) }
         ATTRIBUTE "CLASS" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 6;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_0_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 7;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_1_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 7;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_2_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 8;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_3_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 10;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_4_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 5;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_5_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 11;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_6_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 12;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "TITLE" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 14;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "VERSION" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 4;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
      }
      DATASET "STATES" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
            H5T_STD_U32LE "CPU ID";
            H5T_STD_U16LE "APP ID";
            H5T_STD_U32LE "Task ID";
            H5T_STD_U32LE "Thread ID";
            H5T_STD_U64LE "Time ini";
            H5T_STD_U64LE "Time fi";
            H5T_STD_U16LE "State";
         }
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 301496 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED ) }
         ATTRIBUTE "CLASS" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 6;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_0_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 7;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_1_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 7;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_2_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 8;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_3_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 10;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_4_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 9;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_5_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 8;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_6_NAME" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 6;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "TITLE" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 14;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
         ATTRIBUTE "VERSION" {
            DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
               STRSIZE 4;
               STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
               CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
               CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
            }
            DATASPACE  SCALAR
         }
      }
   }
}
}
```

Where I basically have 3 datasets under /RECORDS (STATES, EVENTS and COMMUNICATIONS). I think my HDF5 doesn't have anything weird.
I've tried to load these datasets using Pandas and Dask arrays and it works.

**3. What I would like to know**

What is wrong with my HDF5 file making Dask unable to read it as a dataframe?

I've tried to find in the Dask documentation what requirements HDF5 files must satisfy, but there is nothing covering this topic. If at least I knew what problem my file has, I would be able to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PR https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/6204 was merged recently into dask master that, with luck, solved this issue for you.

Comment: Indeed, that merge solves the problem. Thank you very much! :)